# Writing Intelli-J inspections?

Tags: intellij-idea, code-hinting, inspections

How would I go about writing my own Intelli-J inspection? I'm looking for some general guides or resources.

I want to bring up an inspection hint every time a collection class is instantiated manually, rather than through the Guava (`List.newArrayList()/Maps.newHashMap()`) etc. as per a team-wide standard.

I'd appreciate any direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such an inspection you don't need to write a plug-in, instead use the [Structural Search and Replace](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/ssr.html) (SSR) feature which allows to create custom inspections with quick fixes.

See also the [Creating your own inspections](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/static_code_analysis.html) section and [documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-own-inspections.html) for this feature.

Note that it's available in the Ultimate version only.

Comment: Is there an easy way to capture types? I can't seem to do basic things like use variable expressions side by side, such as $mapType$$mapEnd$ to do a simple replacement. Is there any reason this might be?

That is, if I have a single expression, say .*\s*.*abc, and I break it into two variables, .*\s* and .*abc, the expression does not match any text. What could be going wrong?

Comment: SSR matches one or many language constructions per variable, it will NOT capture several variables ($mapType$$mapEnd$) into type reference.
If I understand you correctly you need to match
List<$Type$> $variable$ = new $ListType$<$Type$>()
and replace it accordingly.

Comment: This topic has more detailed information on the subject http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302233/intelli-j-structural-search-and-replace-problems

Comment: How does one provide custom description for a custom SSR inspection?

Answer (score 2):

I'll have to disappoint you but there are no written guidelines nor resources nor documentation for almost everything related to plug-ins  and IntelliJ :(.
(this is the main reason many IntelliJ fans haven't worked on plug-ins for their favorite tool).

That company makes  fantastic products, but when it comes to documentation, books, and guidelines for developers (not users) - well, they're practically non-existing :(.

Your only bet is to take a look the source of actual IntelliJ plug-ins (some of them are here: http://git.jetbrains.org/) and ask very concrete questions on the [IntelliJ plug-in list](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/idea/plugins) since the development team will gladly answer you usually in a matter of minutes.

Comment: This is the saddest response I've ever had. I don't know if I'm that willing to jump down the rabbit hole.

Comment: It's not that it's impossible. There are already incredibly good plug-ins for IntelliJ. Just that those developers are very very skilled (compared to me) and are able to code without docs (I'm not :( ). Maybe they also like coding puzzles - and this quite close to it. It's also not that I'm so bad (I hope so :) ), since I was able to code plug-ins for Netbeans and Eclipse very easily, but there was good documentation available.