# IntelliJ structural search and replace problems

Tags: java, regex, replace, intellij-idea, structural-search

Is there an easy way to capture types? I can't seem to do basic things like use variable expressions side by side, such as `$mapType$$mapEnd$` to do a simple replacement. Is there any reason this might be? That is, if I have a single expression, say `.*\s*.*abc`, and I break it into two variables, `.*\s*` and `.*abc`, the expression does not match any text. What could be going wrong?

```
Example template:
$var1$ = $impl$

Example second template:
$var1$ = $type$$implEnd$
```

If `$impl$` is a full regular expression, placing `$type$` and `$implEnd$` together with half of the matching regex causes patterns not to match. What could be going wrong?

I'm trying to do this transformation:

```
List<String,Object> list = new ArrayList<String,Object>();
List<String,Object> list = Lists.newArrayList();
```

Clearly, I need to capture "Array" somehow, as well as only those types which have no arguments.

Comment: SSR matches one or many language constructions per variable, it will NOT capture several variables ($mapType$$mapEnd$) into type reference (or whatever language lexem is).
If I understand you correctly you need to match
List<$Type$> $variable$ = new $ListType$<$Type$>()
and replace it accordingly.
You might find this article usefull http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/ssr.html

Comment: This almost works, but it does not preserve the commas between the arguments to the generic. The article you linked is very vague and high-level.

Comment: You can have several type arguments to be specified, as needed, like
Map<$Key$, $Value$>. I believe that semicolon lost in first pattern is a bug. Btw, the article is full of concrete examples (collected at the point of writing :)

Comment: Ah, it would have been nice to allow arbitrary amounts of arguments for certain types. Oh well.

Comment: @nicity: Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSR matches one or many language constructions per variable, it will NOT capture several variables ($mapType$$mapEnd$) into type reference (or whatever language lexem is). 
For code like

`List<String> someName = new ArrayList<String>();`

one needs to have search pattern

`List<$Type$> $variable$ = new $ListType$<$Type$>()`

and replace it accordingly. 
For more complex generic expressions one needs to consider several generic type variables like `Map<$Key$, $Value$>`
One might find this article useful (many concrete SSR example patterns)

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/ssr.html